# Using Train function for multiple factors

Tags: r, time-series, regression, r-caret

I have a time series with 3 currencies that I am trying to use the train function for. While I able to perform the regression when only using 1 currency, and thus not including the factor, I get the following warning when I use the time series with 3 currencies:

Error: wrong model type for classification

Additionally, 2 of the currencies do not have data for the complete time series period.

Below is the code in question:

```
myTimeControl <- trainControl(method = "timeslice",initialWindow =  
99,horizon = 6,fixedWindow = TRUE)

plsFitTime <- train(ForwardLocalRate~.,
data = mydata,method = "lm",
preProc = c("center", "scale"), trControl = myTimeControl)
```

mydata is a xts object with the date plus 15 columns.

Thanks

Comment: `train` should need a data frame and not an `xts` object (there is no `train` method for that). Otherwise, we would need a small reproducible example to know.

Comment: Then what's the best way to use it for a time series? Additionally, if some dates have 1 result and others have 3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you read your data, but I think you need to specify the type of data

Try:

```
y <-read.csv ("mydata ", colClasses=c("ForwardLocalRate"="character"))
```